# ffmpeg h.264 options to pipe into VLC for MJPEG streaming

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, h.264

I am trying to get VLC to recognize ffmpeg libx264 h.264 output from a `stdin` pipe.

I have a source of raw RGB24 video (currently a file, but eventually realtime from an app) that I wish to h.264 encode with ffmpeg, then pipe into VLC to serve over HTTP as an MJPEG stream. I can get this to work if I use the OMX hardware encoder, but my app is modifying frames from the Raspberry Pi camera, so it will have the hardware encoder tied up. Because of the way the MMAL pipeline works, my app cannot output h.264 when it is processing frames. This means I have to use the ffmpeg libx264 encoder on the raw frames. (Unfortunately according to the muxer listing on the VLC [streaming features](https://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html) page, VLC can't produce MJPEG from raw input.)

This is my VLC command, which I know works. I can either drive this with h.264 output from my program to `stdin`, or use `cat` to pipe a raw h.264 file into this. I can connect to it on my LAN at `http://raspberrypi.local:8554/`. Line breaks added for readability:

```
cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#transcode{
vcodec=mjpg,vb=2500,fps=24,acodec=none}
:standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;
boundary=7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},
mux=mpjpeg,dst=:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

The ffmpeg command produces a valid h.264 file (I've transcoded a sample to MP4), but VLC doesn't like it (neither as `stdin` nor if I `cat` the file through a pipe). Also with line breaks for readability:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner 
-f rawvideo -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s:v 640x480 -r 24 -i - 
-f h264 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -
```

For testing from a terminal, I just `cat /media/ramdisk/output.raw | ffmpeg... | vlc...` using the two command lines above.

As noted previously, I can't use OMX, but if ffmpeg output is configured as shown below, it all works fine. I know OMX output is much lower quality but I don't understand the other ways in which it differs, or what libx264 switches might produce working output.

```
-f h264 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 2500k
```

I've run mediainfo against the output from both encoders, although I don't know what most of this means.

libx264:

```
General
Complete name                            : /media/ramdisk/libx264.h264
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
File size                                : 1.43 MiB
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=6 / threads=4 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=1 / slices=4 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High 4:4:4 Predictive@L3
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 24.000 FPS
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=6 / threads=4 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=1 / slices=4 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
```

OMX:

```
General
Complete name                            : /media/ramdisk/h264_omx.h264
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
File size                                : 2.39 MiB

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=12
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
```

Comment: Very belatedly, if you're outputting a final MJPEG stream, why get H.264 involved at all? You introduce several seconds of latency for little if any benefit. Convert the original source to MJPEG and your latency should be in the sub-100ms range, ie almost realtime

Comment: @ChrisDavies I neglected to mention it, but I'm also writing the output to MP4. It was a security camera scenario so I wanted to be able to record and view at the same time. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking back to when I ran real-time auctions across Western/Central Europe and 300ms latency was our upper permitted limit

Answer (score 0):

After studying the mediainfo output for a bit, the answer was as simple as changing the libx264 output to yuv420p by adding this switch:

```
-vf format=yuv420p
```